# Subpixel rendering makes inner div smaller than parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create a layout that uses a grid inside of another grid. However, when we use percentage values for sizes, the browser sometimes creates a width containing decimal values.

This behavior is breaking my layout, making the "right" grid 1px wider than the "top" child grid, causing a green border on the right.

[image: right border]

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  margin: 2rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 960px;
}

.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(180px, 25%) minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 11px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(30px, 10%) 1fr;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #ECECEC;
}

.top {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 100px;
 
}

.top-block {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-grid">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="https://cdnbr2.img.sputniknews.com/images/1395/55/13955519.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="top">
        <div class="top-block">1</div>
        <div class="top-block">2</div>
        <div class="top-block">3</div>
        <div class="top-block">4</div>
        <div class="top-block">5</div>
        <div class="top-block">6</div>
        <div class="top-block">7</div>
        <div class="top-block">8</div>
        <div class="top-block">9</div>
        <div class="top-block">10</div>
        <div class="top-block">11</div>
        <div class="top-block">12</div>
        <div class="top-block">13</div>
        <div class="top-block">14</div>
        <div class="top-block">15</div>
        <div class="top-block">16</div>
        <div class="top-block">17</div>
        <div class="top-block">18</div>
        <div class="top-block">19</div>
        <div class="top-block">20</div>
        <div class="top-block">21</div>
        <div class="top-block">22</div>
        <div class="top-block">23</div>
        <div class="top-block">24</div>
        <div class="top-block">25</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Source: https://jsfiddle.net/09xs51an/2/

Sometimes this doesn't occur, depending on how wide the area is. If you want to play around, set the scroll to the right, and change the width of the viewing area on the JSFiddle.

Solutions I've tried involved messing with the justify-content property, but it breaks the scrolling.

What can I do to avoid this?